# How to find the norm of the image of the vector $v$ = $(-3, 5, 1)$ under the map $B \circ A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ be two linear maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, corresponding to rotations by $30$ degree around x-axis, and rotation by $22\frac {1}{2}$ degree around z-axis respectively. what is the norm of the image of the vector $v$ = $(-3, 5, 1)$ under the map $B \circ A$?

sombody please help.

Comment: The first question you should ask is whether a rotation can change the length of a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two methods available.

You might find the matrices representing these two maps $A,B:\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, do the matrix composition, and then just find the length. This would be a good exercise in writing out matrices for linear transformations, especially as rotations are relatively tame.

Or you might realize that rotations don't change length, and in fact rotation matrices are orthogonal matrices. So the ending length is the same as the initial length.